# How can I make a webpage gradient ASP.NET and CSS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

How can I make a webpage gradient ASP.NET and CSS?  For example, the gradient starts with light blue and ends with white?

Answer (score 0):

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-css-gradient

Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

try [Css3Please](http://css3please.com/), to generate a cross browser gradients,

although [ColorZilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) have a very nice gradient editor tool!

for example, the following css style should give you what you need:

```
background-color: #00aeef;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#00aeef), to(#ffffff)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #00aeef, #ffffff); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #00aeef, #ffffff); /* FF3.6 */
background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #00aeef, #ffffff); /* IE10 */
background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #00aeef, #ffffff); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background-image:         linear-gradient(top, #00aeef, #ffffff);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#00aeef', EndColorStr='#ffffff'); /* IE6–IE9 */
```

Comment: Firstly, IE9 doesn't support `filter` - it is supposed to be standards compliant, so it should pick up the standard one. Secondly, for IE8, you should use `-ms-filter`. Thirdly, I'd suggest using CSS3Pie with IE, so you can drop those horrible `filter` styles altogether.